# When to save data to SQLite (data changes on broadcast received)

Tags: android, sqlite

I am building an app that counts the number of device unlocks.
I am using `BroadcastReceiver` to detect when user unlocks the phone and save it in `SharedPreferences`. Then, when user opens the app, I save number of unlocks in `SQLite`.
What is the best way to save/update unlocks? 
Use a `JobScheduler` and sync unlocks few times a day? (By syncing I mean getting from shared preferences and updating  `SQLite`).
I suppose that updating database every time a broadcast is received is a bad practice.

Comment: Why not just use SQLite all the time? What do sharedpreferences add to this?

Comment: I thought that it is not memory efficient way. Basically I am saving only unlocks number (int) and current date (String). So is it okay to save data to SQL on every broadcast received?

Comment: I don't see why not. It's opening a file and writing to it just like sharedpreferences

Comment: Okay, so I will just do this that way. Thank You for help.

Comment: its ok... i guess you don't have a very big data base ... on lock unlock you can directly update your data base using a backgourd service